# How can i remove this spacing from my li?

Tags: html, css

Im making a navigation with `li` but it has a weird bit of whitespace on the left on the navigation, Any ideas how i can get rid of it ?

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/RqbuU/

As you can see in the jfiddle, The first blue box has some white space

**Here is an image of what i want to remove**

[image]

Comment: add padding-left:0 to the ul

Comment: or move the id on the `ul`, because it doesn't seem you need two containers anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the following CSS:

```
#navigation ul {
    padding:0;
}
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RqbuU/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

This looks like default styles that the web browser is adding by default. You can indeed implement CSS for this as someone has mentioned:

```
#navigation ul{  
     padding: 0;
}
```

Or, to make life easier on yourself, you could use normalize.css to reset the default styles on most major browsers. [Normalize CSS](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Just implement that into your styles folder and add a style tag into your header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
```